# Is there a way to determine object type returned from ASP.NET MVC controller in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

Is there a way to determine object time after you get response from ASP.NET MVC controller? I have inherited objects and I need to determine which object type I receive to build the AngularJS object?

Comment: I am not sure what do you want exactly, have you tried to look at [type of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) operator?

Answer (score 0):

You can add additional property like

```
       class BaseType{
          public string TypeName { get; set; }
       }
```

Which you can initialize in each inherited class, like this

```
        class InheritedType: BaseType
        {
             public InheritedType()
             {
                  TypeName=typeof(InheritedType).Name;
             }
        }
```